# Netbeans reports "Insufficient memory to compile" results in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors, noclassdeffounderror

After attempting to run my Java application, Netbeans 7.4 reports I have "insufficient memory". Afterwards my application runs fine up to a point where it encounters a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

At this point my project is set to "Compile On Save", I've been told that disabling this would make it compile and run fine, which it does, but this just cripples my workflow. I really depend on being able to Compile On Save.

I've already clean and built everything and my `CLASSPATH` has been properly set. I know its a Netbeans specific issue, I've heard its got to do with corrupted cache and I don't recall exactly what folder I need to delete in order to reset Netbeans cache to be able to compile everything properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some additional research, turns out since Netbeans 7.2 the cache location has been moved to

`C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\`

Deleting the IDE's version folder "7.4" clears cache and seems to fix the issue for now.